# Populating a text box using MVVM/LINQ and XAML

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

I am trying to learn about MVVM and LINQ, so am setting up a test database.  The XAML based view has a single TextBox - bound to "OrgName".  However, I've been working on an example, but I am having trouble with "var result" (I think).

For some reason, I get a runtime error under the heading "XamlParseException occurred", which I think is down to the query string, not pulling in the field.

As requested the full error is:
{"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication2.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9'."}

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private egwEntities db = new egwEntities();
    MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = mvm;

        var result = (from o in db.egw_addressbook select o).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
        {
            mvm.OrgName = result.org_name;
        }
    }
}
    public class MyViewModel
    {
         public string OrgName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAMLI am using in the view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="EGW" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding OrgName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="72,94,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm sorry you are having problems. If you tell us about your problems, people may actually be able to help you.

Comment: I suppose that might help....

Comment: An exception is a runtime error. You say you get a compile error. Somehow you failed to mention what line it's in and what *exactly* it says. If you need help, you need to learn to file a complete, answerable question first. Programming is not witchcraft. We cannot hex away your error. Your compiler already determined what is wrong. It told you loud and clear. If you need help deciphering the message, you will need to post the message here.

Comment: I am knew to this so any help and guidance is appreciated (but manners cost nothing).  Have you even looked at the code, to see if there are any obvious errors?

Comment: XamlParseException usually means that is something wrong with your Xaml.

Comment: Thanks for that - I have added the XAML code, but I still thing it has something to do with my LINQ variable.

Comment: The error remains if you comment this row?

Comment: It's definitly the var string (after commenting it out), it ran just fine, and I think I've spotted where I'm going wrong:  "from o in db.egw_addressbook select o".  In the query string example the "o" doesn't relate to anything.  I would guess it should be "from ??? in db.egw_addressbook select org_name" or similar.....any suggestions?

Comment: 'o' is fine, it is an anonymous variable and they are an intrinsic part of LINQ. It basically means "from (whatever a single element in this collection is, assigned to a variable 'o') select 'o'"

Comment: You can also use the method syntax for that simple query, and could use: `var result = db.egw_addressbook.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the

```
var result = (from o in db.egw_addressbook select o).FirstOrDefault();
if (result != null) {
    mvm.OrgName = result.org_name;
}
```

is failing, causing the MainWindow construction to fail, giving the XamlParse exception. You can test this by removing these lines an seeing if it runs.

**MVVM** 
One of the goals of the MVVM shape is to reduce linkage between the View (window) and the data.  In the example above you are missing the Model from Model-View-ViewModel shape (or rather you have merged the Model and View).

You might try it this way.

Separate out the data access in to a repository - makes for easier testing

```
public interface IRepository {
    IEnumerable<Organization> GetOrganizations();
}
```

I have a used a dummy repository, you would replace this with your DataContext code

```
public IEnumerable<Organization> GetOrganizations() {
    return new[] {new Organization() {Name = "A name"}};
}
```

Add a model for the application

```
public class AppModel {

    public AppModel(IRepository repository) {

        var result = (from o in repository.GetOrganizations() select o).FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null) {
            OrgName = result.Name;
        } 
    }

    public string OrgName { get; private set; }

}
```

**Note:** 
This can be done in a few ways. We tend to have very thin ViewModels with a lot of member replication between the ViewModel and model (e.g. the OrgName appearing in both); the ViewModels being mainly pass-through and formatting.  This is not the only way to do it (and may not even be the best). I would do a web search on MVVM shapes to follow up

I have tweaked the viewmodel code a bit. If you are not writing to the OrgName then it should be readonly

```
public class MainWindowViewModel {

    private readonly AppModel _model;

    public MainWindowViewModel(AppModel model) {
        _model = model;
    }

    public string OrgName {
        get { return _model.OrgName; }
    }

}
```

If the OrgName is readonly then the binding needs to be oneway. Adding a datacontext definition helps chasing down binding errors.

```
<Window x:Class="Sus.ProofsOfConcept.SimpleMvvm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyExamples.SimpleMvvm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance views:MainWindowViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=false }"
    Title="EGW" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding OrgName, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="72,94,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318"/>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

The default running mechanism (startup Window named in App.Xaml) no longer works, absent messing around with Dependency Injection (DI) you can use

```
public partial class App : Application {

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        var model = new AppModel(new Repository());
        var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(model);
        var view = new MainWindow() {DataContext = viewModel};
        view.Show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Fantastic Alan - It's a really new way of working for me so trying to get my head around this type of architecture is taking some time, but with help like this (and some good reading), I'll get there.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with your XAML, which will throw runtime errors if you have syntax errors. If there was a problem with your `var result` line you'd probably have received some other error.

Try changing your TextWrapping line to this:

`TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap`